# Can I manipulate a web page to avoid open a new tab, and display the content in the same tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I visit the webpage of my university a lot, but it open many tabs to reach the page I want to visit, so I end with 4 tabs open at the end, I was wandering, can I manupilate a web page to avoid open a new tab, and display the content in the same tab?

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? There are several good extensions built to do just this.

Comment: Can you not find the url of the last opened tab and access it directly?

Comment: Thanks, but  I want to learn to do it by myself, so no bookmark and extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing forcing links to open in new tabs/windows is the target attribute on the anchor tags.

If jQuery is loaded on the page you could remove them by typing this into the address bar

```
javascript:$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
```